# Legally valid signature in LaTeX

Tags: signatures

Is it possible to create a legally valid signature in LaTex? I can't find anything on that subject.

Let us say I want to create a NDA. How do I sign it using LaTeX?

https://www.docusign.com/blog/are-electronic-signatures-legal

Comment: As far as I know, you can sign a PDF electronically. But this process needs to be done after the PDF has been compiled. At least this is the case by PDFs generated via other software I know. Also, I would assume that the legal status of electronic signatures and especially the details differ from country to country. So, to really know whether this very set up you chose to sign your documents electronically is legal in the relevant jurisdiction, you should probably consult a lawyer.

Comment: signature *fields* can be added with acrotex/eforms. I also plan to add support to l3pdffield when I have some time. The eforms manual, `eformman` shows also an example how a signature can be added with latex, but it requires the password in the source and I wouldn't recommend that.